# Release control from init.d script centos

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I am using logstash-forwarder and starting it inside its init script with the command:

```
/opt/logstash-forwarder/bin/logstash-forwarder -config=/etc/logstash-forwarder -spool-size 100
```

This command produces output and does not release control. This is my script:

[pastebin link for the init script](http://pastebin.com/8nTNkRQH)

it is slightly changed from the book version as that doesnt set spool size, but this has nothing to do with problem that I am having.

So, given the above script, if, in the terminal, I issue the command:

```
service logstash-forwarder start
```

It starts, prints output to stdout, but does not release, so I have to ctrl c, and that kills  the process.

I have tried setting exit 0 after start, and also putting output to /dev/null, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&` at the end of your `logstash-forwarder` command. That will cause the job to be run in the background, and allow the script to finish.